# How do you make two instances communicate with echotor through the same class?

Tags: c#, methods, instance

Let's say I have a people class. I'd have a cash property and a name property in that people class which when it gets initialized I can set the amount of cash and the name I want.
Let's say I want to make a give method where it takes cash from the people object and gives it to the other people object and takes it away from the people object that gave it. Now I know I can just put it outside of the class and let (x) object give to (y) object AFTER they get initialized, but that's not what I want.
I want a method that can take variables and it before I actually initialized the object so after I do initialize it all I gotta do is fill in the parameters.

I know this might be confusing so I'd do some examples to better elaborate what i'm saying.

So lets say my people class is like this:

```
class People
{
    private decimal cash;
    private string name = "";
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    public decimal Cash
    {
        get { return cash; }
        set { cash = value; }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to set in that same class for instance 1 of the class to give cash to instance 2 of the class?

I tried making another class named bet and putting a method in there. But I get the same problem as when I try putting it in the people class.
I can't do

```
public void give (People person, decimal amount)
{
    person.cash += amount 
    person.cash -= amount
}
```

Because i'm working with the same variable and it would just give the amount and take the amount for the SAME object.

Do I HAVE to make one method to give and one to take? How would that work if I want it to be dynamic and want only methods to call and not manually have to + and - amounts from the objects I initialize in the form?

Keep in mind i'm really new at this and I don't know how to use events yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should transfer money from the current person to another, please investigate my implementation of Give method

```
class People
{
private decimal cash;
private string name = "";
public string Name
{
get { return name; }
set { name = value; }
}
public decimal Cash
{
get { return cash; }
set { cash = value; }
}

public void Give(Person target, decimal amount)
{
  Cash -= amount;
  target.Cash += amount;
}
}
```

Comment: Ooohhh didn't think of it like this. Thanks alot!  I know th

Comment: @zespri how? I don't see an accept answer button. Or do you mean just saying I accept the answer? In that case :I officially accept this answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass 3 parameters to the function
e.g.

```
class People
{
private decimal cash;
private string name = "";
public string Name
{
get { return name; }
set { name = value; }
}
public decimal Cash
{
get { return cash; }
set { cash = value; }
}

public static void Give(People p1,People p2, decimal amount)
{
  p2.Cash -= amount;
  p1.Cash += amount;
}
}
```

you can also use solution provided by Viacheslav but for that you have to take caution about the object that is calling the Give function but in this method you can call the method directly from class, you don't need an object to call the function.

Comment: Ohh yea! Wow thanks alot for saying this method! This will definitely be useful!